# Screen video Recording for objective c

Tags: objective-c, video, video-capture, video-recording

I've searched the web for having a good resource to implement a code in objective c that is able to record a video of the screen of the Ipad while the user is doing some actions to capture his performance, but I didn't get a clue. Is there anyway to make it possible?

Comment: @Karthik yeah the [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/AVScreenShack/Introduction/Intro.html) is helpful it supplies you a project of how to record a screen in xcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download sample from the link below provided by Apple.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/AVScreenShack/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: If you would like to use a service and a framework, I suggest [FlightRecorder](http://www.flightrecorder.co). It's an amazing service.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can only record your applications view only.
You can use the demo here [iPhone Screen Capture Revisited](http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/673)